# Discrete event simulation of a prioritized lunch queue in Java (Data structures)

Tags: java, simulation

(See also the [Algorithms part](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113607/discrete-event-simulation-of-a-prioritized-lunch-queue-in-java-algorithms).)

**Post details**

The program I am putting for being reviewed does not fit entirely in a single post, so I have to resort to the equation by [Niklaus Wirth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklaus_Wirth):

> Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs

This part is about data structures: a set of classes that do not do anything fancy. Of course, you could consider `PrioritizedQueue` (to be posted in the **Algorithms part**) to be a **data structure**, yet I have to place it to the Algorithms part after all.

**Simulation**

I am considering a (hopefully fictional) academic setting, where there is a lunch cafeteria in a campus. The academic society recognizes four **privilege levels** (listed from most privileged to least privileged):

1. doctors (PhD),
2. masters (MSc),
3. bachelors (BSc),
4. undergraduates.

Now, for example, when a master goes for a lunch, he **skips** all undergraduates and bachelors in the queue, and appends him-/herself to the end of queue consisting of masters.

(If a user want to consider a **fair** queue, he/she could just create a population with each member with the same academic degree.)

As often, we do this for gathering **statistics**: we gather minimum, average and maximum waiting times for each privilege level; also, we compute the standard deviation of the waiting times within each privilege level. Apart from that, we also compute the same set of statistical variables for the **idle time** of the cafeteria cashier.

**Code**

**AcademicDegree.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

/**
 * This class implements an enumeration over academic degrees.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 2, 2015) 
 */
public enum AcademicDegree {

    // The order denotes priority from highest to lowest.
    DOCTOR       ("PhD"),
    MASTER       ("MSc"),
    BACHELOR     ("BSc"),
    UNDERGRADUATE("Undergraduate");

    private final String description;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

    private AcademicDegree(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**Cashier.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import static net.coderodde.simulation.lunch.Utils.checkMean;
import static net.coderodde.simulation.lunch.Utils.checkStandardDeviation;

/**
 * This class models the action of a cashier.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 4, 2015)
 */
public final class Cashier {

    private final double meanServiceTime;
    private final double standardDeviationOfServiceTime;
    private final Random random;

    /**
     * Initiates a strong fluent API for creating a {@code Cashier}.
     * 
     * @param  random the random number generator to use.
     * @return the mean service time selector.
     */
    public static MeanServiceTimeSelector withRandom(Random random) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(random, "The input Random is null.");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.random = random;
        return new MeanServiceTimeSelector(configuration);
    }

    /**
     * Initiates a strong fluent API for creating a {@code Cashier} using a 
     * default random number generator.
     * 
     * @return the mean service time selector. 
     */
    public static MeanServiceTimeSelector withDefaultRandom() {
        return withRandom(new Random());
    }

    public final static class MeanServiceTimeSelector {

        private final Configuration configuration;

        private MeanServiceTimeSelector(Configuration configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        /**
         * Selects the mean service time and returns a standard deviation 
         * selector.
         * 
         * @param  meanServiceTime the mean service time in seconds.
         * @return a standard deviation selector.
         */
        public StandardDeviationSelector 
            withMeanServiceTime(double meanServiceTime) {
            checkMean(meanServiceTime);
            configuration.meanServiceTime = meanServiceTime;
            return new StandardDeviationSelector(configuration);
        }
    }

    public final static class StandardDeviationSelector {

        private final Configuration configuration;

        private StandardDeviationSelector(Configuration configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        /**
         * Selects a standard deviation for the service time and returns the 
         * {@code Cashier} using the gathered parameters.
         * 
         * @param  standardDeviationOfServiceTime the standard deviation of the
         *                                        service time in seconds.
         * @return a {@code Cashier} object.
         */
        public Cashier withStandardDeviationOfServiceTime(
                double standardDeviationOfServiceTime) {
            checkStandardDeviation(standardDeviationOfServiceTime);
            return new Cashier(configuration.meanServiceTime,
                               standardDeviationOfServiceTime,
                               configuration.random);
        }
    }

    private Cashier(double meanServiceTime, 
                    double standardDeviationOfServiceTime,
                    Random random) {
        this.meanServiceTime = meanServiceTime;
        this.standardDeviationOfServiceTime = standardDeviationOfServiceTime;
        this.random = random;
    }

    public int getServiceTime() {
        return (int)(Math.round(meanServiceTime + 
                                    standardDeviationOfServiceTime * 
                                    random.nextGaussian()));
    }

    private static final class Configuration {
        private Random random;
        private double meanServiceTime;
    }
}
```

**LunchQueueEvent.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

/**
 * This class describes a lunch queue event.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 2, 2015).
 */
final class LunchQueueEvent implements Comparable<LunchQueueEvent> {

    private final Person person;
    private final int timeStamp;

    LunchQueueEvent(Person person, int timeStamp) {
        this.person = person;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    }

    Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    int getTimestamp() {
        return timeStamp;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(LunchQueueEvent anotherEvent) {
        return Double.compare(timeStamp, anotherEvent.timeStamp);
    }
}
```

**Person.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class implements a record for a person.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 2, 2015)
 */
public final class Person implements Comparable<Person> {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final AcademicDegree academicDegree;
    private final String stringRepresentation;
    private final String identity;

    public static LastNameSelector withFirstName(String firstName) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(firstName, 
                               "The first name of a person is null.");
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.firstName = firstName;
        return new LastNameSelector(configuration);
    }

    public static final class LastNameSelector {

        private final Configuration configuration;

        private LastNameSelector(Configuration configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public AcademicDegreeSelector withLastName(String lastName) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(lastName, 
                                   "The last name of a person is null.");
            configuration.lastName = lastName;
            return new AcademicDegreeSelector(configuration);
        }
    }

    public static final class AcademicDegreeSelector {

        private final Configuration configuration;

        AcademicDegreeSelector(Configuration configuration) {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }

        public Person withAcademicDegree(AcademicDegree degree) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(degree, "The academic degree is null.");
            return new Person(configuration.firstName,
                              configuration.lastName,
                              degree);
        }
    }

    private Person(String firstName, 
                   String lastName, 
                   AcademicDegree academicDegree) {
        this.firstName      = firstName;
        this.lastName       = lastName;
        this.academicDegree = academicDegree;
        this.stringRepresentation = "[" + firstName + " " + lastName + ", " + 
                                          academicDegree + "]";
        this.identity = firstName + " " + lastName;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public AcademicDegree getAcademicDegree() {
        return academicDegree;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return stringRepresentation;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        return this.academicDegree.compareTo(o.getAcademicDegree());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return identity.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        Person other = (Person) obj;
        return Objects.equals(identity, other.identity);
    }

    private static final class Configuration {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
    }
}
```

**Population.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.Set;
import static net.coderodde.simulation.lunch.Utils.checkTime;

/**
 * This class represents simulated population.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 3, 2015)
 */
public final class Population {

    private final Map<Person, Integer> arrivalTimeMap = new HashMap<>();

    public final class ArrivalTimeSelector {
        private final Person person;

        ArrivalTimeSelector(Person person) {
            this.person = Objects.requireNonNull(person,
                                                 "The input person is null.");
        }

        public boolean withArrivalTime(int arrivalTime) {
            checkTime(arrivalTime);

            if (arrivalTimeMap.containsKey(person)) {
                return false;
            }

            arrivalTimeMap.put(person, arrivalTime);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public ArrivalTimeSelector addPerson(Person person) {
        return new ArrivalTimeSelector(person);
    }

    public int size() {
        return arrivalTimeMap.size();
    }

    Set<Person> getPersonSet() {
        return Collections.<Person>unmodifiableSet(arrivalTimeMap.keySet());
    }

    Queue<LunchQueueEvent> toEventQueue() {
        List<LunchQueueEvent> eventList = new ArrayList<>(size());

        getPersonSet().stream().forEach((person) -> {
            eventList.add(new LunchQueueEvent(person, 
                                              arrivalTimeMap.get(person)));
        });

        Collections.sort(eventList, 
                        (event1, event2) -> {
            // Try to compare by the time stamps of the events.
            int cmp = event1.compareTo(event2);

            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }

            // The two input events have same time stamp, break ties by person
            // priority.
            return event1.getPerson().compareTo(event2.getPerson());
        });

        return new ArrayDeque<>(eventList);
    }
}
```

**SimulationResult.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * This class holds the statistics of a simulation.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 2, 2015)
 */
public final class SimulationResult {

    private static final String NL = "\n";
    private static final String SKIP = "    ";
    private static final int NO_DATA = -1;

    private final Map<AcademicDegree, Integer> waitAverageMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<AcademicDegree, Integer> waitStandardDeviationMap = 
            new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<AcademicDegree, Integer> waitMinMap = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<AcademicDegree, Integer> waitMaxMap = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<Person, LunchQueueEvent> arrivalEventMap;
    private final Map<Person, LunchQueueEvent> servedEventMap;

    private int cashierMinimumIdleTime = NO_DATA;
    private int cashierAverageIdleTime = NO_DATA;
    private int cashierMaximumIdleTime = NO_DATA;
    private int cashierStandardDeviation = NO_DATA;

    public int getMinimumWaitTime(AcademicDegree degree) {
        return waitMinMap.getOrDefault(degree, NO_DATA);
    }

    public int getWaitAverage(AcademicDegree degree) {
        return waitAverageMap.getOrDefault(degree, NO_DATA);
    }

    public int getMaximumWaitTime(AcademicDegree degree) {
        return waitMaxMap.getOrDefault(degree, NO_DATA);
    }

    public int getWaitStandardDeviation(AcademicDegree degree) {
        return waitStandardDeviationMap.getOrDefault(degree, NO_DATA);
    }

    public int getCashierMinimumIdleTime() {
        return cashierMinimumIdleTime;
    }

    public int getCashierAverageIdleTime() {
        return cashierAverageIdleTime;
    }

    public int getCashierMaximumIdleTime() {
        return cashierMaximumIdleTime;
    }

    public int getCashierStandardDeviation() {
        return cashierStandardDeviation;
    }

    SimulationResult(Map<Person, LunchQueueEvent> arrivalEventMap,
                     Map<Person, LunchQueueEvent> servedEventMap) {
        this.arrivalEventMap = arrivalEventMap;
        this.servedEventMap = servedEventMap;
    }

    void putWaitMinimumTime(AcademicDegree degree, int minimumWaitTime) {
        waitMinMap.put(degree, minimumWaitTime);
    }

    void putAverageWaitTime(AcademicDegree degree, int averageTime) {
        waitAverageMap.put(degree, averageTime);
    }

    void putWaitMaximumTime(AcademicDegree degree, int maximumWaitTime) {
        waitMaxMap.put(degree, maximumWaitTime);
    }

    void putWaitTimeStandardDeviation(AcademicDegree degree, 
                                      int timeStandardDeviation) {
        waitStandardDeviationMap.put(degree, timeStandardDeviation);
    }

    void putCashierMinimumIdleTime(int cashierMinimumIdleTime) {
        this.cashierMinimumIdleTime = cashierMinimumIdleTime;
    }

    void putCashierAverageIdleTime(int cashierAverageIdleTime) {
        this.cashierAverageIdleTime = cashierAverageIdleTime;
    }

    void putCashierMaximumIdleTime(int cashierMaximumIdleTime) {
        this.cashierMaximumIdleTime = cashierMaximumIdleTime;
    }

    void putCashierStandardDeviation(int cashierStandardDeviation) {
        this.cashierStandardDeviation = cashierStandardDeviation;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(arrivalEventMap.keySet());

        Collections.<Person>sort(personList, 
                                (p1, p2) -> {
            double arrivalTime1 = arrivalEventMap.get(p1).getTimestamp();
            double servedTime1 = servedEventMap.get(p1).getTimestamp();

            double arrivalTime2 = arrivalEventMap.get(p2).getTimestamp();
            double servedTime2 = servedEventMap.get(p2).getTimestamp();

            return Double.compare(servedTime1 - arrivalTime1, 
                                  servedTime2 - arrivalTime2);
        });

        for (Person person : personList) {
            sb.append(person.toString())
              .append(", wait time: ")
              .append((int)(servedEventMap.get(person).getTimestamp() -
                            arrivalEventMap.get(person).getTimestamp()))
              .append(" seconds.")
              .append(NL);
        }

        toString(sb, AcademicDegree.DOCTOR);
        toString(sb, AcademicDegree.MASTER);
        toString(sb, AcademicDegree.BACHELOR);
        toString(sb, AcademicDegree.UNDERGRADUATE);

        sb.append("Cashier:")
          .append(NL)
          .append(SKIP)
          .append("Minimum idle time:  ")
          .append(getCashierMinimumIdleTime())
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL)
          .append(SKIP)
          .append("Average idle time:  ")
          .append(getCashierAverageIdleTime())
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL)
          .append(SKIP)
          .append("Maximum idle time:  ")
          .append(getCashierMaximumIdleTime())
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL)
          .append(SKIP)
          .append("Standard deviation: ")
          .append(getCashierStandardDeviation())
          .append(" seconds.");

        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void toString(StringBuilder sb, AcademicDegree degree) {
        sb.append(degree.toString()).append(":").append(NL);

        sb.append(SKIP)
          .append("Minimum wait time:  ")
          .append(getMinimumWaitTime(degree))
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL);

        sb.append(SKIP)
          .append("Average wait time:  ")
          .append(getWaitAverage(degree))
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL);

        sb.append(SKIP)
          .append("Maximum wait time:  ")
          .append(getMaximumWaitTime(degree))
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL);

        sb.append(SKIP)
          .append("Standard deviation: ")
          .append(getWaitStandardDeviation(degree))
          .append(" seconds.")
          .append(NL);
    }
}
```

**Utils.java**:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

/**
 * This class contains miscellaneous utilities.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 2, 2015)
 */
final class Utils {

    public static void checkMean(double mean) {
        if (Double.isNaN(mean)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The mean is NaN (not-a-number):");
        }

        if (Double.isInfinite(mean)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The mean is infinite: " + mean);
        }
    }

    public static void checkStandardDeviation(double deviation) {
        if (Double.isNaN(deviation)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The standard deviation is NaN (not-a-number):");
        }

        if (Double.isInfinite(deviation)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The standard deviation is infinite: " + deviation);
        }

        if (deviation < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The standard deviation is negative: " + deviation);
        }
    }

    public static void checkTime(double time) {
        if (Double.isNaN(time)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input time is NaN (not-a-number).");
        }

        if (Double.isInfinite(time)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input time is infinite: " + time);
        }
    }
}
```

(I will post the algorithms part shortly.)

Is my coding style, naming conventions, API design reasonable? Any critique much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Utils` class has a lot of duplicate code. Separate components into methods:

```
package net.coderodde.simulation.lunch;

/**
 * This class contains miscellaneous utilities.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Dec 2, 2015)
 */
final class Utils {

    public static void checkMean(double mean) {
        final String errorStart = "The mean is ";
        checkNaN(errorStart, mean);
        checkInfinity(errorStart, mean);
    }

    public static void checkStandardDeviation(double deviation) {
        final String errorStart = "The standard deviation is ";
        checkNaN(errorStart, mean);
        checkInfinity(errorStart, mean);
        checkNegative(errorStart, mean);
    }

    public static void checkTime(double time) {
        final String errorStart = "The input time is ";
        checkNaN(errorStart, time);
        checkInfinity(errorStart, time);
    }

    private static void checkNaN(String errorStart, double num) {
        if (Double.isNaN(num)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    errorStart + "NaN (not-a-number).");
        }
    }

    private static void checkInfinite(double num) {
        if (Double.isInfinite(num)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    errorStart + "infinite: " + num);
        }
    }

    private static void checkNegative(double num) {
        if (num < 0.0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    errorStart + "negative: " + num);
        }
    }

}
```

This way, you have individual method for each value you have to check for, and it is easier to add another method if you need to.

---

You have a `NL` constant, which is pretty much a `\n`. You use it to append. Instead of doing that, you can easily append the `\n` char itself, which saves a String creation.